# Trouble Restoring database from bak file in mssql-server in ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I am using this command to restore the DB from a bak file which I have included at the
path '/var/opt/mssql/data/'

The full command is..

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [demodb] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/demodb.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
```

When I execute this command , this error I am getting..

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server ubuntu, Line 1
> Directory lookup for the file "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL16\MSSQL\DATA\WideWorldImporters.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

I don't know why it is looking in program files in the D directory path.
Please help me to how restore the Database.

Comment: You didn't specify where to restore the database so it's using the path stored in the backup file. That's exactly what you'd want to do when restoring a database on your server

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server backups keep a record of the mdf/ndf/ldf files that they backed up and restores will attempt to replace them in their original locations unless you instruct them to do otherwise.

Have you tried to use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK=N'/var/opt/mssql/data/demodb.bak'` to see which files the backup set contains?  Ref: [RESTORE FILELISTONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql). Based on your error message this should output something similar to:

```
LogicalName  PhysicalName
------------------------------------------
WWI_Primary  D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL16\MSSQL\DATA\WideWorldImporters.mdf
WWI_Log      D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL16\MSSQL\LOG\WideWorldImporters.ldf
```

Armed with the `LogicalName`s shown above you can then [restore a database and move files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_db_n_move_fileshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql) to their new homes using something similar to:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [demodb]
  FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/demodb.bak'
  WITH RECOVERY,
  MOVE N'WWI_Primary' TO N'/var/opt/mssql/data/WideWorldImporters.mdf',
  MOVE N'WWI_Log' TO N'/var/opt/mssql/data/WideWorldImporters.ldf';
```

NOTE: On SQL Server for Docker/Linux backup files are typically stored in the `/var/opt/mssql/backup` directory so as to be kept separately from the database files in `/var/opt/mssql/data`.